# Terminating a Program Using Java

Tags: java, exe

If a user executes `foo.exe` on his computer, is there a way to terminate `foo.exe` using a Java program?

Edit: To clear things up, I am talking about a process that was not created by the Java app.

Comment: What's the point? It's already been executed :D

Comment: I really should have seen that coming. :P

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/81902/576139

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are on Windows .

The command to kill a process is: `taskill` or `tskill` depending your Windows version .

`tskill yourprocessname`

executed by java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"tskill", "foo"});
```

Comment: So you would run this with the same arguments you would use in the command line? (taskkill /im "foo.exe")