# how to stop a running batch file using java

Tags: java, process, cmd

I need to start a batch using java and after a few seconds i need to stop the running batch file.

here is my code

```
try {
        Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start  D:/test.bat");
        Thread.sleep(20*1000);
        process.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my code failed to stop the batch file.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't that simple since you have to kill an independent operating system process you have just started. Looks like [How to find and kill running Win-Processes from within Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902) might help you.

In short: you have to find the PID of a batch script (actually, of a `cmd` process running your batch script) and kill it using `taskkill`.

Answer (score 0):

If the batch is running in cmd.exe using Java, run this

```
Process prClose = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /im cmd.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run a `java` or `javaw` on your .bat file, you need to terminate your batch file first:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im jqs.exe") ;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im javaw.exe") ;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im java.exe") ;
```

And stop cmd(if needed)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe") ;
```

Hope this help!