# Kill all processes in a directory in Java (Windows)

Tags: java, windows, process, kill

Is there a way I can stop all processes in a certain directory through Java? I need my java program to stop all processes in directory "X" on my C:\ drive.

Comment: You might find this link useful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902/how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java

Comment: what is the meaning of 'processes' in a directory? All process which has open handles to 'directory'?

Comment: Do you mean all processes whose executables live in a particular directory?  All processes whose current directory is set to a particular directory?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch from java a console commands, for example

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("taskkill /IM notepad.exe");
int exitValue = p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are suite of tools from [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals). You can query processes and take actions on them. well there is not much to do with Java.

See some info on [handles](http://blad.wordpress.com/2006/05/11/fuser-on-win32/)