# how to count number of pages printed? java

Tags: java, printing

I want to create a program in java which counts the number of prints taken from a printer...What I was trying to do is, When i give a print command through an application such as MS word, my printer starts a particular process...

Is there a method to recognize when that process is initiated?... (provided i am currently running the Java program).. so that i can just increment a counter whenever that print process is initiated, and hence i might be able to keep a track of pages printed.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Google perhaps?

Comment: yes.. Obviously I tried, but just I find the way to count the pages when I print through my java program and want to track all the printed activities

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: I want to do for windows

Answer (score 0):

You can write a infinitely running thread and monitor for the process you are looking for, and increment the counter when you see it.

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902/how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java) to get the code to monitor active process.