# Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?

Tags: java, python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

There is a test, smth like:

```
 import //needed imports

 public class TestClass{
    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       //some code
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       //some code, including init of driver (geckodriver)
    }

   //@After
   // public void tearDown() {
   //  driver.quit();
   //}
}
```

So, I inited geckodriver, and successfully running my tests, using firefox instances. 
But I want Not to close firefox window after each run, because I just want to analyse what I have, and fix any needed, after test run(I'm going to unComment driver.quit() later).
At the same time, each calling without closing the driver leads to over-impact to RAM on my PC(and does not matter - did I close browser manually, or not, after test):
[image]

So, question is:
is there any way to close the process(more precisely - do smth, which will close geckodriver.exe process in taskmgr) of "geckodriver", but will NOT close the browser after test finished? e.g., adding some method in test itself, whatever... This not impacts my work/test itself, I just want to add some optimizing.

Comment: try this to kill process from tasklist - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902/how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per your question commenting out **`driver.quit()`** just `Not to close firefox window after each run, because I just want to analyse what I have` won't be a part of best practices.

**For any detailed analysis we can create log entries and take snapshots.**

While automating through **`Selenium`** as per the best practices you should invoke the **`quit()`** method within the `tearDown() {}`. Invoking **`quit()`** `DELETE`s the current browsing session through sending **"quit"** command with **{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}** and finally sends the **GET** request on **/shutdown** `EndPoint`. Here is an example below :

```
1503397488598   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/8e457516-3335-4d3b-9140-53fb52aa8b74 
1503397488607   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,4,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
1503397488821   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /shutdown
```

So on invoking **`quit()`** method the `Web Browser` session and the `WebDriver` instance gets killed completely. Hence you don't have to incorporate any additional steps which will be an overhead.

---

### Solution

Still if you want to execute kill the dangling `WebDriver` instances e.g. **`GeckoDriver.exe`** instances you can use either of the following code block to kill any of the dangling `WebDriver` instances :

- Java Solution(Windows):

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;

  public class Kill_ChromeDriver_GeckoDriver_IEDriverserver 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe /T");
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T");
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe /T");
      }
  }
  ```
- Python Solution (Windows):

  ```
  import os
  os.system("taskkill /f /im geckodriver.exe /T")
  os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")
  os.system("taskkill /f /im IEDriverServer.exe /T")
  ```
- Python Solution(**Cross Platform**):

  ```
  import os
  import psutil

  PROCNAME = "geckodriver" # or chromedriver or IEDriverServer
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
      # check whether the process name matches
      if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
          proc.kill()
  ```

Comment: psutils way saved me... i was scratching my head for so long ... thank you!