# how to kill drivers after running the automation scripts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run the automation scripts using java-Selenium TestNG.
For opening browser I have invoked chrome driver. even after stopping  the scripts the chrome driver is running in Background process in task manager. 
For ex If I execute my script for 20 time then the chrome driver is running for 20 time in the task manager. I didnt face any issue because of this problem. but still wanted to know should I add anything in my script to stop those drivers? . Will it cause any issue in the future ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can kill unclosed process writing in @AfterSuite (in Java)

If You launch test on Windows:

```
//kill chromedriver
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f");
```

If You launch test on Linux:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "killchrome.sh"};
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and in killchrome.sh (in this example file is in main project directory) you should write

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'chromedrive[r]' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
try{
  ==========      ==========
    YOUR CODE GOES HERE
  ==========      ==========

} catch (Exception e) {
  ==========      ==========
    YOUR CODE GOES HERE
  ==========      ==========
} finally{
  driver.quit();
}
```

It is always a good practice to close your instance in your finally block.

Answer (score 2):

Kill Multiple Processes From the Command Line The first thing you’ll need to do is open up a command prompt, and then use the taskkill command with the following syntax:

```
taskkill /F /IM <processname.exe> /T
```

These parameters will forcibly kill any process matching the name of the executable that you specify. For instance, to kill all iexplore.exe processes, we’d use:

```
[![taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
driver.quit();
```

This will kill shut down the driver and kill the instance.

Answer (score 0):

This script `taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq geckodriver.exe" /F` could kill geckodriver for you. If you want to kill chromedriver, just replace the name with newer name