# Chrome processes are not killed after using quit() method on Chrome 65

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I've problem after update my Chrome browser to Version 65.0.3325.162 (latest)

When my tests start after done each method in task manager there appear  extra zombie Chrome process which take many resources of CPU.

[image: Task manager]

IS there any change with method driver.quit() on Chrome 65? I will add that, on previous version of Chrome browser all was OK.

I use data provider so using method quit() is necessary for correctly working on my test suite.

I use mothod terminate() to close browser after each test class.

My stuff:
Windows 10
Selenium WebDriver 
ChromeDriver 2.36
Selenium WebDriver 2.20

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    protected void terminate() {
        if (browser != null) {
            try {
                browser.quit();
                browser = null;
            } catch (UnreachableBrowserException ex) {
                TestReporter.log(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (NoSuchSessionException noSuchSessionException) {
                TestReporter.log("Tried to quit browser with NULL session: " + noSuchSessionException.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (application != null) {
            application = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)

Comment: Could be a bug.  I found similar issue on old versions of chrome. https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3378.  check in git if there is any existing ticket for your issue.

Comment: I've never known a version of Chrome that didn't do this.

Comment: it worked for me with below solution

Answer (score 1):

Update to new version of Chrome browser resolved my problem. It seems that Chrome 65.0.3325.162 had issue, which caused creation many zombie Chrome processes.

Answer (score -1):

1) Get the driver as singleton

```
@Singleton
class BrowserInstance {

ChromeDriver getDriver(){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
    options.addArguments("--headless --disable-gpu")
    return new ChromeDriver(options)
   }
}
```

2) Use Close and quit in finally block

```
finally {
        chromeDriver.close()
        chromeDriver.quit()
    }
```

Result: you will be using only one instance at time and if you see task manager you will not find chromedriver and chrome process hanging.