# Cannot run program "START": error=2, No such file or directory while trying to kill Chrome process in MAC

Tags: java, macos, selenium, unix, selenium-webdriver

My IDE is eclipse and I'm using **Selenium Webdriver on MAC**. Every time I execute my code below, I want to kill/close the previously opened browser and then start a new instance and leave it on. As a result, only one instance of browser should be open at a time. I am not doing this for testing purpose. I'm just doing this because I want to automate a task.

This is the error I am getting everytime I execute my code:

```
Cannot run program "START": error=2, No such file or directory
```

This is my code:

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    try{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("START taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

This is working fine on **windows**. How do I fix this on **MAC/unix/** environment or what changes should I make in my code?

I was told this error is something to do with **admin privileges** so I should run eclipse as an admin. So I did this: `sudo open Eclipse.app/` . So the eclipse opened as admin and executed the code but I was still getting the same error.

Comment: Why you kill driver process with terminal? Just add driver.quit() in before each step.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question using the following line of code :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
```

to kill the *Browser Client* process will be against all the *Best Practices*.

While automating through **`Selenium`** as per the best practices you should invoke the **`quit()`** method within the `tearDown() {}`. As per the [**`WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) invoking **`quit()`** `DELETE`s the current browsing session through sending **"quit"** command with **{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}** and finally sends the **GET** request on **/shutdown** `EndPoint`.

As an example incase of *GeckoDriver* (W3C compliant WebDriver variant) here are the sequence of events :

```
1503397488598   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/8e457516-3335-4d3b-9140-53fb52aa8b74 
1503397488607   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,4,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
1503397488821   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /shutdown
```

So on invoking **`quit()`** method, the **Web Client** session and the **WebDriver** instance gets killed completely. Hence you don't have to incorporate any additional steps which will be an overhead.

### Solution

Replace the line of code :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
```

With :

```
driver.quit();
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**`Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

### Additional Considerations

- Ensure that the **WebDriver Binary** is having executable permission for non-root users. (`chmod 777`)
- Ensure that the **WebDriver Binary** is present in the specified location.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.