# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died with ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: selenium, jenkins, gson, selenium-chromedriver, selenoid

I'm running a bunch of test cases every hour using selenium-java 3.12.0; TestNG; Selenoid with docker, Jenkins.
Sometimes (about 1 out of 10 cases)  I get the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'autotest.rvkernel.com', ip: '94.130.165.217', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-26-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.39.562737 (dba483cee6a5f15e2e2d73df16968ab10b38a2bf), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.gURWcu}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=67.0.3396.62, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 56c4b100a95d89b3d5702ec8a1a0698a
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:564)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement$1.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:376)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.click(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.click(EventFiringWebDriver.java:389)
    at com.Elements.Element.lambda$click$2(Element.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at com.Elements.Element.click(Element.java:98)
    at com.Elements.Element.click(Element.java:78)
    at com.pages.landing.social.MailRuRegisterPage.clickRegister(MailRuRegisterPage.java:37)
    at RulVulaknTests.authorization.AuthorizationTest.authorizationUserFromMailRU(AuthorizationTest.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:571)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot decode response content: 
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'autotest.rvkernel.com', ip: '94.130.165.217', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-26-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.execute(JsonInput.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:1576)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:534)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.lambda$peek$0(JsonInput.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.execute(JsonInput.java:168)
    ... 37 more
```

And after this error all remained tests are skipped.

Versions of chrome browser using which I have encountered the error - 66, 67.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your Chrome Driver version? Latest is 2.41

Comment: @Squiggs chrome driver 2.38 is embedded in chrome 66 browser docker image, provided by Selenoid; and similarly 2.39 is embedded in chrome 67. so I haven't tried 2.41.

Comment: Though you have removed the `<blockquotes>` now but the trace log formats are broken now. Pretty tough to debug. Consider updating the question with fresh set of error trace logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

...implies that the **RemoteWebDriver** instance was closed abruptly.

Your code trials would have been of some help to debug the issue. Perhaps yout main issue can be one of the following:

- You have mentioned that you are using **selenium-java 3.12.0** but your error trace logs mentions about **selenium-java 3.6.0**. So possibly there are multiple instances of **selenium-java** referenced within this *project*. So you need to ensure that your *project* is configured with only one set of **selenium-java** binaries.
- As per *best practices*:

  - Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
  - Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
  - Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
  - (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
  - (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
  - If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- As you have mentioned *running a bunch of test cases every hour* possibly there are multiple dangling instances of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* which can be viewed through the **process list** (Linux OS) or **TaskManager** (Windows OS). You need to always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- If the dangling instances of *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* still persists consider killing them with brute force. You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)
- Incase you program is attempting to *set up TCP connections from ports that are greater than 5000* you can refer this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196271/when-you-try-to-connect-from-tcp-ports-greater-than-5000-you-receive-t)
- References

  - [org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4319)
  - [Getting "Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died." with chromedriver](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3153)
  - [IE11: UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4929)
  - [WebDriver fix for UnreachableBrowserException](http://matejtymes.blogspot.com/2014/10/webdriver-fix-for-unreachablebrowserexc.html)

Comment: `Build info: version: '3.6.0'`    - perhaps it is not about selenium version, cause I checked that there is only 1 selenium maven dependency in my project:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the reply to very old questions, but thought it could help someone else.
I was facing the same problem, and earlier I also thoughts issue is with Webdriver but it was not the case,

```
public static final Target EMAIL = Target.the("email")
    .locatedBy(("//input[(@id='login-email-input')]"));
```

And everything was working fine with,

```
actor.attemptsTo(Enter.keyValues("someemail@gmail.com")
    .into(EMAIL).thenHit(Keys.TAB));
```

but I thought to clear the input box before enter the new value and replaced above line with,

```
actor.attemptsTo(Clear.field(EMAIL));
actor.attemptsTo(Enter.keyValues("someemail@gmail.com")
   .into(EMAIL).thenHit(Keys.TAB));
```

And I got the same error. After removing newly added line, things started working correctly.