# chromedriver.exe is not killable in widows after calling driver.quit()

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am using selenium for automation test. I am calling `driver.quit()` in all my script under finally block.

But still, after some periodic run I am able to see many chromedriver.exe is piled up on my task manager. Sometimes I am getting the exception when I call driver.quit() not always.

> Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Whenever I get the above exception then, I am not able to end the process using task manager. I am not able to kill using taskkill command also.

If I kill using taskkill command(`taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe`) it says 
ERROR: The process "chromedriver.exe" with PID 4052 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

If I use `taskkill /F /PID 4052`
ERROR: The process with PID 4052 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

Still many chromedriver was listed under task manager

[image]

This is not a duplicate question of [stop geckodriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)

Here my problem is, I am not able to kill the process chromedriver.exe using taskkill command also.

Note: Once I restart the windows all the chromedriver.exe were killed.

Comment: What test runner are you using?

Comment: try with driver.close();

Comment: @selenium this is not a duplicate question.