# Out of Memory Error when Web Scraping with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape the Marathi Matrimony website using Python and Selenium. The website has a total of 365 pages, but I am only able to successfully scrape the first 130 pages. After that, the website stops responding and displays an "Out of Memory" error.

I have tried refreshing the page, but it doesn't resolve the issue. Upon refresh, the website resets the current page to 1, requiring me to click the "Next" button 130 times again to start extracting information.

Here is an overview of my code:

```
# Create ChromeOptions and set incognito mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://matches.marathimatrimony.com/')

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='MIDP']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='PASSWORD2']")))
                                           
#enter username and password
username.clear()
username.send_keys("EMAIL")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("PASSWORD")

# Wait for the login button to be visible
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit'][value='LOGIN']")))

# Click the login button
button.click()

sleep(2)

# Find the element using the CSS selector
ad_close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span > img[alt='Close button']")))

# Click the element
ad_close_button.click()

sleep(2)

# Find the element using the CSS selector
all_matches = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[routerlink='/listing']")))

# Click the element
all_matches.click()

# Create a DataFrame to store the data
columns = ["Profile Name", "Profile Href", "Profile ID", "Page Number"]
data2 = []
current_page_number = 1
last_page_scraped = 0
count = 1

while current_page_number <= 375:
    if current_page_number <= last_page_scraped:
        print("Current page is not equal to the last page scraped")
        while current_page_number <= last_page_scraped:
            next_page_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='pagination-next']//a")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page_element)
            current_page_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class, 'current')]/span[2]")
            current_page_text = current_page_element.text
            current_page_number = re.search(r'\d+', current_page_text).group()
            current_page_number = int(current_page_number)
            print(f"Moved to page: {current_page_number}")
        sleep(2)
    else:
        print(f"Scraping page number: {current_page_number}")
        # Find the profile elements
        profile_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.listingMatchCard")
        # Loop through each profile element
        for profile in profile_elements:
            try:
                profile_name_element = profile.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.clr-black1.text-decoration-none.col-md-12.pl-0")
                profile_name = profile_name_element.text
                profile_href = profile_name_element.get_attribute("href")
                profile_id_element = profile.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cursor-pointer.outline-none.text-decoration-none.clr-grey2")
                profile_id = profile_id_element.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1]
                data2.append([profile_name, profile_href, profile_id, current_page_number])
                count += 1
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("Error occurred while scraping a profile. Skipping...")
        last_page_scraped = current_page_number
        print(f"Successfully scraped page number: {last_page_scraped}")
        if current_page_number % 5 == 0:
            # Save the scraped data every 5 pages
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns)
            filename = f"scraped_profiles/scraped_profiles_page_{current_page_number}.csv"
            df2.to_csv(filename, index=False)
        try:
            next_page_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.pagination-next a")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page_element)
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        sleep(2)
        current_page_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class, 'current')]/span[2]")
        current_page_text = current_page_element.text
        current_page_number = re.search(r'\d+', current_page_text).group()
        current_page_number = int(current_page_number)
        print(f"The current page is: {current_page_number}")

# Save the final scraped data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns)
filename = f"final_scraped_profiles.csv"
df2.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

I have also tried the following approach to navigate to the desired page. So that I can save the files in batches but same thing happens. Even with this approach, the website becomes unresponsive again after 130 clicks of the next page button. I tried to search for the link on the website which can directly navigate me to the page number 130, but I was unable to find it on the website. Hence I had to click the next button 130 time to again start scrapping.

```
target_page_number = 135

while True:
    try:
        current_page_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class, 'current')]/span[2]")
        current_page_text = current_page_element.text
        current_page_number = re.search(r'\d+', current_page_text).group()
        current_page_number = int(current_page_number)
        if current_page_number >= target_page_number:
            break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    
    print(f'current page is:{current_page_number}',end='\r')
    next_page_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='pagination-next']//a")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page_element)
    sleep(2)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve the "Out of Memory" error and successfully scrape all the pages of the website.

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: After reaching on page 130 the website stop responding showing `Error code: Out of Memory` and at my end the code is still running their is no error message. Once I refresh the page manually the website reset the current page to page number 1 and hence the code automatically starts executing the lines moves the current page to page number 130. And after 130 clicks to move the current page to last scraped page the website again stops responding and shows `Error code: Out of Memory`. The same thing happens again

Comment: Does either of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59750032/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60320289/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499679/7429447) discussion helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try clearing out the `data2` after saving since you *already saved it*?

```
...
       if current_page_number % 5 == 0:
            # Save the scraped data every 5 pages
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns)
            filename = f"scraped_profiles/scraped_profiles_page_{current_page_number}.csv"
            df2.to_csv(filename, index=False
            data2 = []
...
```

Also, after the loop you might need to check if data is already saved.

```
if current_page_number % 5 != 0:
```