# Closing a specific chromedriver proccess

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have several drivers running connected to .NET core applications in Windows SO.
Unfortunately, the application may crash due to an error. 
When I see this situation, I need to close the application and browser manually, but the chromedriver process continues to run.
How do I identify which chromedriver matches the application I closed?
The question on [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling) dont resolve this need.

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Each time you initiate the execution of your tests a fresh set of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) is created. So neither you are going to use the previous **zombie** *ChromeDriver* instances nor you would be able to access them.

---

### Conclusion

The only optimal approach will be to kill them all and free up your system memory and you can use the following solution:

- Python Solution(**Cross Platform**):

  ```
  import os
  import psutil

  PROCNAME = "chromedriver"
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
      # check whether the process name matches
      if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
          proc.kill()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)

Comment: The problem in this case is that there are other tests running. If I close all processes, I will need to restart all other tests.

Comment: @MikailhP In all likelihood you won't trigger a cleanup when tests are getting executed within the same system.