# How to fix [WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I access Websites in a loop via selenium Java based. Some of the sites crash imediately so that i get the error

```
[1618982990.911][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

after a short time.

So this is not a selenium issue i assume, since even chrome crashes if i visit the site manually because of js errors, saying unresonsive Website

My problem is, that every time a site crashes, chromedriver and a chrome instance will stay alive so that i have high CPU usage after a short time.

Can i tell selenium to quit the instance if it is frozen? But i dont know how this should be possible if it does not get answer from chrome anymore?

Thankful for any solution or idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes with some Windows version driver.quit() will not kill the chrome process which I have come across.
So at the end of the script you can kill the chrome processes if exists using java code, if the driver.quit doesn't work.

Please refer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902/how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20command%20line,exec()%20.&text=You%20could%20use%20a%20command,SysInternals%20PsKill%20and%20SysInternals%20PsList.) link which has the code to kill the process if exists in Java and pass the chrome process to it.

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround for anyone who would be interested. First setting up a pageLoadTimeout, after that force any chrome instance to  be killed if an Exception is being thrown.

```
 try{
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//some excecution code....
}

catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error. Closing");
        driver.quit();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timerChromeKillListener = new Timer();
timerChromeKillListener.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            try
            {
                final Logs logs = driver.manage().logs();
                final LogEntries driverLog = logs.get("driver");
                if (driverLog != null)
                {
                    final List<LogEntry> logEntries = driverLog.getAll();
                    for (final LogEntry logEntry : logEntries)
                    {
                        final String message = logEntry.getMessage();
                        if (message.contains("Unable to evaluate script: disconnected: not connected to DevTools") || message.contains("Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying..."))
                        {
                            disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ignored)
            {
            }
        }
    }
} , 1 , 100);
```